# How to get the difference in value between subsequent observations (country-years)?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr, panel-data

Let's say, I have scores for 5 countries over a period of 10 years such as:

```
mydata<-1:3
mydata<-expand.grid(
country=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
year=c('1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989'))
mydata$score=sapply(runif(50,0,2), function(x) {round(x,4)})

library(reshape)
mydata<-reshape(mydata, v.names="score", idvar="year", timevar="country", direction="wide")

> head(mydata)
   year score.A score.B score.C score.D score.E
1  1980  1.0538  1.6921  1.3165  1.7434  1.9687
6  1981  1.4773  1.6479  0.3135  0.6172  0.7704
11 1982  0.8748  1.3704  0.2788  1.6306  1.7237
16 1983  1.1224  1.1340  1.7684  1.3352  0.4317
21 1984  1.5496  1.8706  1.4641  0.5313  0.8590
26 1985  1.7715  1.8953  0.6230  0.3580  1.6313
```

Now, I would like to create a new variable "period" that is 1 if the score of the subsequent year is +/- 0.5 different from the score of the previous year and that is 0 if this is not true. I would like to do so for all 5 countries. And it would be great if it were possible to identify the country-years for which period = 1 and display this information in a table.

```
> head(mydata)
   year score.A score.B score.C score.D score.E  period.A  period.B ...
1  1980  1.0538  1.6921  1.3165  1.7434  1.9687   NA         NA
6  1981  1.4773  1.6479  0.3135  0.6172  0.7704   0          ....
11 1982  0.8748  1.3704  0.2788  1.6306  1.7237   1
16 1983  1.1224  1.1340  1.7684  1.3352  0.4317   0
21 1984  1.5496  1.8706  1.4641  0.5313  0.8590   0
26 1985  1.7715  1.8953  0.6230  0.3580  1.6313   0
```

I very much hope that this is not too much to ask. I tried it with `dist` in the `library(proxy)` but I do not know how to restrict the function to pairs of observation rather than the full row. Thanks a million!!

Comment: Just a quick note that you should switch to using `reshape2` since `reshape` is now deprecated and not in development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one uses `diff` and `lapply`:

```
score.cols  <- grep("score", colnames(mydata), value=TRUE)
period.cols <- gsub("score", "period", score.cols)
compute.period <- function(x)as.integer(c(NA, abs(diff(x)) > 0.5))
cbind(mydata, `names<-`(lapply(mydata[score.cols], compute.period), period.cols))
```

**Edit:** It becomes more apparent (with your other question posted this morning) that maybe you are not working with the right data structure. Instead, I would recommend you do your work on the raw (before it is reshaped) data:

```
period.fun <- function(x)as.integer(c(NA, abs(diff(x) > 0.5)))
mydata <- within(mydata, period <- ave(score, country, FUN = period.fun))
```

Only then you would reshape `mydata` to get it in its final form.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. I tick your's as 'accepted' as it is the most parsimonious. Many many thanks : )

Comment: Yupp, a really nice solution. Could you perhaps explain, what `name<-` does? I changed the last line to    cbind(mydata, `names<-`(apply(mydata[score.cols], 2, compute.period), period.cols)) but then I get the original colnames twice...

Answer (score 3):

First, create the data, using `set.seed()` to make it reproducible:

```
set.seed(1014)
mydata <- expand.grid(
  country = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
  year = 1980:1989
)
mydata$score <- round(runif(50, 0, 2), 4)
head(mydata)

#>   country year  score
#> 1       A 1980 0.1615
#> 2       B 1980 1.6687
#> 3       C 1980 1.2015
#> 4       D 1980 0.3144
#> 5       E 1980 0.0148
#> 6       A 1981 0.9328
```

Next, use dplyr to break into countries and compare each value to the
previous:

```
library(dplyr)
out <- mydata %.% 
  group_by(country) %.%
  mutate(big_diff = abs(score - lag(score)) > 0.5)

out %.% 
  arrange(country, year) %.% 
  head(10)

#> Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#> Groups: country
#> 
#>    country year  score big_diff
#> 1        A 1980 0.1615       NA
#> 2        A 1981 0.9328     TRUE
#> 3        A 1982 1.7492     TRUE
#> 4        A 1983 0.3913     TRUE
#> 5        A 1984 0.5798    FALSE
#> 6        A 1985 1.4830     TRUE
#> 7        A 1986 0.0625     TRUE
#> 8        A 1987 0.8643     TRUE
#> 9        A 1988 1.3603    FALSE
#> 10       A 1989 1.5312    FALSE
```

After this you could coerce `big_diff()` to a number, and use reshape to
move `country` to the columns, but I probably wouldn't because it will
be harder to work with in future steps. See [tidy
data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringr)
periods <- function(mydata) {
# pull out columns with score in the title
score_columns <- mydata[, str_detect(names(mydata), "score")]
# make a copy to store the periods
period_columns <- score_columns
# rename the columns in periods
names(period_columns) <- str_replace_all(names(period_columns), "score", "periods")

for ( i in 1:length(score_columns))
    { 
        offset <- c(NA,score_columns[2:length(score_columns[,i])-1,i])
            # if the diff is > 0.5, return 1 else return 0.
        period_columns[, i] <- ifelse(offset - score_columns[,i]>0.5, 1, 0)
    }

 return(cbind(data,period_columns))
}

# Then simply call the function on your data. It should work with variable number
# of score columns.

> periods(mydata)
   year score.A score.B score.C score.D score.E periods.A
1  1980  1.8251  1.3168  0.9264  1.4921  0.9870        NA
6  1981  0.7603  1.7270  0.0324  1.8332  0.7147         1
11 1982  1.5245  0.6904  1.1699  0.5918  0.3029         0
16 1983  0.5280  0.2333  1.4395  1.2145  0.7273         1
21 1984  1.8739  1.8420  0.9940  0.2886  1.5975         0
26 1985  1.8794  0.7352  1.1665  0.9859  1.1301         0
31 1986  1.8002  0.3546  0.3885  1.9985  1.7183         0
36 1987  1.7985  1.0536  1.8445  0.8573  1.9307         0
41 1988  1.8444  0.6644  1.4765  0.2586  0.5531         0
46 1989  0.7342  0.4921  0.5816  0.8954  0.9359         1
   periods.B periods.C periods.D periods.E
1         NA        NA        NA        NA
6          0         1         0         0
11         1         0         1         0
16         0         0         0         0
21         0         0         1         0
26         1         0         0         0
31         0         1         0         0
36         0         0         1         0
41         0         0         1         1
46         0         1         0         0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (also for the advice to use reshape2 instead of reshape)! The loop works and nicely captures what I was looking for. Great!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just one line with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2<-mydata%.%group_by(country)%.%mutate(period = c(NA, as.numeric(abs(diff(score))>0.5)))
```

Then you can reshape it with `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df2,year~country)
```

Results:

```
   year  A  B  C  D  E
1  1980 NA NA NA NA NA
2  1981  0  1  0  0  1
3  1982  1  0  1  1  0
4  1983  1  0  1  0  1
5  1984  1  1  0  1  1
6  1985  1  0  1  0  0
7  1986  1  1  1  0  1
8  1987  1  1  0  0  0
9  1988  0  0  1  1  1
10 1989  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: I think it would be a little clearer here to use `lead()` or `lag()`

Comment: @hadley  Yeah, I think you are right! And with lag or lead it seems that you don't have to "fix" the vector size adding the NA manually.

Comment: Yup, that's why I added them :)