# How to create new variable based on the difference between two observations that indicates the direction of change?

Tags: r, variables, loops, dataframe

Imagine, you have performance scores of five countries for a period of ten years. You do know that the performance of some countries considerably changed at specific years. Now, you would like to know whether they changed in a positive or in a negative way. It is this last step that troubles me.

**Sample data:**

```
mydata<-1:3
mydata<-expand.grid(
country=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
year=c('1980','1981','1982','1983','1984','1985','1986','1987','1988','1989'))
mydata$score=sapply(runif(50,0,2), function(x) {round(x,4)})
library(reshape)
mydata<-reshape(mydata, v.names="score", idvar="year", timevar="country", direction="wide")
```

**Identification of change:**

```
score.cols <- grep("score", colnames(mydata), value=TRUE)
period.cols <- gsub("score", "period", score.cols)
compute.period <- function(x)as.integer(c(NA, abs(diff(x)) >= 0.5))
cbind(mydata, `names<-`(lapply(mydata[score.cols], compute.period), period.cols))

> cbind(mydata, `names<-`(lapply(mydata[score.cols], compute.period), period.cols))
   year score.A score.B score.C score.D score.E period.A period.B period.C period.D period.E
1  1980  0.4029  0.3308  1.0432  0.7405  0.7254       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
6  1981  1.7577  0.5479  1.4437  1.3996  0.8454        1        0        0        1        0
11 1982  1.9603  0.5404  1.2687  1.4317  0.0203        0        0        0        0        1
16 1983  0.5509  1.5834  1.3954  0.4935  0.4994        1        1        0        1        0
21 1984  1.9672  1.0628  1.8436  0.4327  0.0144        1        1        0        0        0
26 1985  1.6799  1.5873  0.5898  0.9553  1.3475        0        1        1        1        1
31 1986  1.2918  1.7049  0.3448  0.1841  0.9270        0        0        0        1        0
36 1987  0.1719  0.3297  0.6386  0.4075  1.8494        1        1        0        0        1
41 1988  0.7123  1.2378  0.9220  0.3278  1.5888        1        1        0        0        0
46 1989  0.2998  0.4418  1.0640  1.1405  0.7034        0        1        0        1        1
```

**Identification of direction of change:**

```
direct.cols<-gsub("score", "direction", score.cols)
compute.direction<-function(mydata){
for (i in 1:length(score.cols))
{ 
direct.cols[,i] <- ifelse((period.cols[i] == 1) & (score.cols[i] >= score.cols[i-1]), 1, 
+ ifelse((period.cols[i] == 1) & (score.cols[i] <= score.cols[i-1]), 2,
+ ifelse((period.cols[i] != 1), 0, NA)))
}}
cbind(mydata, `names<-`(lapply(mydata[score.cols], compute.direction), direct.cols))
```

**PROBLEM:**
When running the last step, I get the following error message:

```
    Error in direct.cols[, i] <- ifelse((period.cols[i] == 1) & (score.cols[i] >=  : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

*Why? And what am I doing wrong?*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a million.

This question builds on the great answers by [flodel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201032/flodel) and [Maiasaura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313163/maiasaura) to a question I asked earlier [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443202/how-to-get-the-difference-in-value-between-subsequent-observations-country-year]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443202/how-to-get-the-difference-in-value-between-subsequent-observations-country-year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to replicate what I have suggested for your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443202/how-to-get-the-difference-in-value-between-subsequent-observations-country-year), then your `compute.diff` should be a function that only takes a vector of scores as input. It will be applied to each of the `score.A`, `score.B`, etc. columns in your data. So you should use something like:

```
compute.direction <- function(x) {
   x.diff <- c(NA, diff(x))
   ifelse(x.diff > 0.5, 1,
          ifelse(x.diff < -0.5, 2,
                 NA))
}
```

However, look at the edit I made to my answer on that previous question: it seems more and more like you are not working with the best data structure. Instead of appending multiple blocks of columns (five for `period`, five for `direction`), I'd suggest you work first on the raw (non-reshaped data):

```
mydata <- within(mydata, period    <- ave(score, country, FUN = compute.period),
                         direction <- ave(score, country, FUN = compute.direction))
```

and then only reshape your data.

Comment: Juhu -- I just applied it to my own data set and it works : ) It was a very good idea not to reshape the data, makes it less complicated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The object `period.cols` is a vector and hence 1-dimensional. Use

```
period.cols[i]
```

to access the `i`th value of it.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I removed the commas and edited the above entry accordingly. Now, I get a new error message: `Error in direct.cols[, i] <- ifelse((period.cols[i] == 1) & (score.cols[i] >=  : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`. Any ideas?